# Jenkins sudo: a terminal is required to read the password (beginner)

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, cicd

I get an error when I'm trying to run some scripts with sudo. Before that, I integrated Jenkins with Gitlab-server (Gitlab-server wasn't install Jenkins, Jenkins in another server) and I add some permission to Jenkins in my /etc/sudoers in Gitlab-server.

This is my Jenkins file:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'gitlab-server'
    }
    tools {
        maven '3.6.3'
    }
    environment {
        appUser = "shoeshop"
        appName = "shoe-ShoppingCart"
        appVersion = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
        appType = "jar"
        processName = "${appName}-${appVersion}.${appType}"
        folderDeploy = "/datas/${appUser}"
        buildScript = "mvn clean install -DskipTests=True"
        copyScript = "echo '123' | sudo -S cp -r target/${processName} ${folderDeploy}"
        permsScript = "sudo chown -R ${appUser}. ${folderDeploy}"
        killScript = "sudo kill -9 \$(ps -ef| grep ${processName} | grep -v grep | awk '{print \$2}')"
        runScript = 'sudo su ${appUser} -c "cd ${folderDeploy}; java -jar ${processName} > nohup.out 2>&1 &"'
    }
    stages {
        stage('build') {
                steps {
                    sh (script: """ ${buildScript} """, label: "build with maven")
                }
        }
                stage('deploy') {
                steps {
                    sh (script: """ ${copyScript} """, label: "copy the .jar file into deploy folder")
                    sh (script: """ ${permsScript} """, label: "set permission folder")
                    sh (script: """ ${killScript} """, label: "terminate the running process")
                    sh (script: """ ${runScript} """, label: "run the project")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is content in /etc/sudoer

```
# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/cp*
jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/kill*
jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/chown*
jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/su shoeshop*
# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers
```

the error is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFk9v.png)
I look forward to receiving your help and greatly appreciate it. thank you very much

Comment: *what* errors are you getting? (please [edit] your question with the details)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read up on [ask]. I've changed your title to something less chatty and more meaningful than irrelevant statements (whether you're new to Jenkins or not has no bearing on any possible solution) copied from the post start. Please do check whether my phrasing of your question is accurate. If not, do [edit] the post to rectify.

Comment: sorry, I have just updated the error. Thank you